# Image Draw9Patched is stretched on the wrong area

Tags: android, imageview, stretch, nine-patch

After Draw9Patching some image I had in my drawable folder, I want to make it have a certain height.

At start I have this picture :

[image: http://www.izipik.com/images/201201/03/jmqwcflam23smmi7kh-g1rze56g1rze56g1.png]

Then, when I apply ScaleType to "fitXY" in order to "strech" my image, and when I define my height, it's incorrect :

[image]

The arrow on the bottom of my imageview get stretched, however I mentioned on my draw9patch not to stretch this area.

Do you have any explanation of this problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're sure your 9patch is good, try setting it as a background and not using the scaletype at all.

Comment: The image set as a background is not stretched at all, in fact, it's exactly the same image as if it was only put as an imageview ... :

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure 9patches are meant to be used as *backgrounds* of Views, not as the source of an ImageView. If you set the background of a TextView to this 9patch, everything will work fine.